# Passar valor de um select para Html.BeginForms - Asp .Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho esse elemento `<select>`:

```
 <select id="status" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="arquivo" >
            @{ foreach (string valor in ViewBag.ListaArquivos)
                {
                    <option value="@valor">@valor</option>
                }
            }

        </select>
```

O Controller espera um parâmetro do tipo `string`.

Gostaria de saber como posso passar o valor selecionado para esse `Html.Beginforms`:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("MostrarDocumentos", "Usuario", new { arquivo = } ,FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" }))
        {

            <a href="javascript:;" target="_blank" onclick="document.forms[0].submit(); ">Visualizar</a>
            <hr />
        }
```

Quero pegar o `value` do `<select>` e enviar pelo `Html.BeginForms`, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pode postar o código da controller? Ou pelo menos o cabeçalho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por que você colocou seu campo de seleção `<option value="@valor">@valor</option>` fora do seu `form`? Se você quer envia-lo pra controller faz sentido deixar ele no seu formulário.

Se entendi bem, você quer apenas fazer um submit do valor selecionado para a `Controller` `MostrarDocumentos`.

Então você só precisa disso:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MostrarDocumentos", "Usuario", null, FormMethod.Post, new { target = "_blank" }))
{
    <select id="status" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="arquivo">
        @{ foreach (string valor in ViewBag.ListaArquivos)
            {
                <option value="@valor">@valor</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" value="Enviar" target="_blank" />
}
```

Caso tenha algum motivo pra montar sua drop down list fora do seu form ou pra fazer seu submit `onclick="document.forms[0].submit();"` especifique esses motivos na sua pergunta.

E o exemplo acima funcionará apenas se você tiver a **Controller MostrarDocumentos** com requisição **POST** com um parâmetro do tipo **string** conforme especificou no comentário.

Exemplo da Controller que receberá o submit:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MostrarDocumentos(string arquivo)
{
    //Código da minha controller que recebe o submit...
    return View();
}
```